# How to capture the result of \StrSubstitute into a macro?

Tags: macros, strings

I have a macro, say defined as follows:

```
\edef \temp{A.input 1}
```

I want to replace the dot with hyphen and have the result being stored in `\mystart`. Something like that:

```
\edef \mystart{\StrSubstitute{\temp}{.}{-}}
```

`\show \mystart` should ouput `A-input 1`.

I've messed up with many variants, but none of them works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Syntax:

```
\StrSubstitute[<number>]{<string>}{<stringA>}{<stringB>}[<name>]
```

Usage:

```
\StrSubstitute{\temp}{.}{-}[\mystart]
```

Comment: I must be blind. Shame on me :)