# StrSubstitute for multiple replacements in a loop?

Tags: macros, loops, foreach, xstring

I am trying to replace multiple keywords using `\StrSubstitute` inside a loop using `foreach` - but unable to accumulate all the results. The result of each `\StrSubstitute` call is getting lost inside the loop.

I am using the method suggested at [capturing the result](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16404/how-to-capture-the-result-of-strsubstitute-into-a-macro). Sample code is as below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\KeyWords{one, two, three}
\def\MyText{This is one, followed by two later by three}
\expandarg

Original Text: \MyText\\

\foreach \keyword in \KeyWords
{
   Replacing: \texttt{\keyword}
  \StrSubstitute{\MyText}{\keyword}{\textbf{\keyword}}[\MyText]

  Now MyText: \MyText  \\ \\
}
Final: \MyText \
```

In the above sample, in each iteration the particular word one, two or three gets bold correctly - but when it finally comes out of the loop, the `\MyText` ends up being the same as original.

Even `\csgdef` did not work (assuming global vs local definitions is the problem).

Tried  `\renewcommand{\MyText}{\StrSubstitute{\MyText}{\keyword}{\textbf{\keyword}}}` to directly assign the substitution result to `\MyText` but it just hangs saying something like

```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
```

(I am using `MikTeX` 2.9 and `pdflatex` if that matters )

What is the correct mechanism to achieve this?

Goal is to substitute one or more comma separated supplied keywords with their respective replacement words in a given string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that each cycle of `\foreach` is performed inside a group. So you have to globally save `\MyText` after the substitution; however a straightforward

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\KeyWords{one, two, three}
\def\MyText{This is one, followed by two later by three}
\expandarg

Original Text: \MyText\\

\foreach \keyword in \KeyWords
{
  Replacing: \texttt{\keyword}
  \StrSubstitute{\MyText}{\keyword}{\textbf{\keyword}}[\temp]%
  \global\let\MyText\temp

  Now MyText: \MyText  \\
}
Final: \MyText 
\end{document}
```

will not work, because the keywords are replaced by `\textbf{\keyword}`, where `\keyword` doesn't get expanded.

You have to expand `\keyword` in the substitution string; for instance with

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\KeyWords{one, two, three}
\def\MyText{This is one, followed by two later by three}
\expandarg

Original Text: \MyText

\foreach \keyword in \KeyWords
{
  Replacing: \texttt{\keyword}
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \unexpanded{\StrSubstitute{\MyText}{\keyword}}
    {\noexpand\textbf{\keyword}}}\x[\temp]
  \global\let\MyText\temp
  Now MyText: \MyText  \\
}
Final: \MyText
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I's suggest a different approach with `l3regex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setkeywords}{m}
 {
  \gopa_set_keywords:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\changekeywords}{ O{textbf} m}
 {
  \gopa_change_keywords:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \gopa_set_keywords:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_gopa_keywords_seq { , } { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_gopa_keywords_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_gopa_keywords_seq { | } }
  \tl_put_left:Nn \l_gopa_keywords_tl { \b( }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_gopa_keywords_tl { ) }
  \regex_gset:NV \g_gopa_keywords_regex \l_gopa_keywords_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \gopa_change_keywords:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_gopa_sentence_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:NnN \g_gopa_keywords_regex { \c{#1}\cB\{\1\cE\} } \l_gopa_sentence_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_gopa_sentence_tl
 }
\tl_new:N \l_gopa_keywords_tl
\tl_new:N \l_gopa_sentence_tl
\seq_new:N \l_gopa_keywords_seq
\regex_new:N \g_gopa_keywords_regex
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_gset:Nn { NV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setkeywords{one, two, three}

\begin{document}
\changekeywords{This is one, followed by two later by three}

\changekeywords[textit]{This is one, followed by two later by three}

\end{document}
```

The `\setkeywords` command defines the keywords to change; with `\changekeywords you specify the text and, optionally, the format to use (only the control sequence name, rather than a command).

How does it work? From the list of keywords, we prepare a regular expression in the form

```
\b ( one | two | three )
```

is built. Matches are replaced by `\textbf{\1}` where `\1` represents the matching string.

[image]

Comment: Thanks much. The `l3regex` approach looks elegant - I am sure regular expressions would match and replace faster than explicit loops. But when I copy paste that code as-is and run on `pdflatex (miktex 2.9)` I am getting errors: `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \seq_use:Nn 
                       \l_gopa_keywords_seq {|}
l.39 \setkeywords{one, two, three}
                                  
? ` Am I missing something? Does latex3 require some special processing?

Comment: tested on TexLive on ubuntu - same error. Added expl3 package reference - no change.

Comment: @GopalakrishnaPalem You have to update to the last version of all packages. For the moment you can try with `\seq_use:Nnnn \l_gopa_keywords_seq {|} {|} {|}`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternate way, using `stringstrings`.  Downside: its a slow package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcounter{index}
\newcommand\emboldenkeywords[2]{%
  \getargs{#1}%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \edef\thestring{#2}%
  \encodetoken[1]{\bfseries}
  \encodetoken[2]{\mdseries}
  \whiledo{\value{index} < \narg}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \edef\nextkeyword{\csname arg\roman{index}\endcsname}%
    \convertword[e]{\thestring}{\nextkeyword}{\bfseries\nextkeyword\mdseries}%
  }%
  \retokenize{\thestring}%
  \thestring%
  \decodetoken[1]{\bfseries}
  \decodetoken[2]{\mdseries}
}
\begin{document}
\emboldenkeywords{one two three}{This is one, followed by two later by three}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. Was not aware of this package `stringstrings` before. Thanks for this approach - I can use some of these concepts.